# Visual Studio Installer dependencies for C++ 2005 and 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, installation, redistributable

I’m a novices at Visual Studio so please forgive me. I’ve been working on a Visual studio 2010 project using Openwebkit sharp. When deploying it on my machine everything works great. However, I have come to discover that Openwebkit sharp has dependencies on “Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistributable 8.0.61001” and “Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 redistributable”. I’m using the Visual Studio Installer for installation. The installer checks for dependences on my main project and add a checker on the installer to see if it’s installed on the destination computer and it does do this. However, is doesn’t not find any C++ dependencies. In the Prerequisites I’ve put a Check mark for it to add the Visual C++ 2010 Runtime Libraries (x86). Yet during installation I never get any indication it even checks these nor do I even think this is the right dependency. In the launch Condition I’ve tried having it check for a GUID and throw a pop up. This seems to work at first and throws a popup saying you must install this Package and stops installation. However once you install that package and hit the installer again the checker says still not found and throws the same popup.  I’ve looked in to registry launch conditions but still have the same issue. 
One issue I have is that the “Microsoft Visual C++ 2005 redistributable 8.0.61001” is only found in a MFC redistributable. I’ve looked into adding the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 redistributable as a merge module, but I never got it to actually install during my installation. I’ve spent hours on the MSDN site and only seem to come out of there more confused than I went in.

Any help you can give me would be much appreciated? Especially if you know of a video tutorial on how to have the installer search the registry to see if these items are installed or how to add the C++ to my resources so that the windows installer find the dependency and adds them itself. Thanks Steve